# Prove $x^n\equiv a\,(\operatorname{mod}m)$ has a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra Exercise I5 of Chapter 23.

> Suppose $m$ has a primitive root, and let $n$ be relatively prime to $\phi(m)$.
>   (Suppose $n > 0$.) Prove that if $a$ is relatively prime to $m$, then $x^n\equiv a\,(\operatorname{mod}m)$
>   has a solution.

Attempt:

Given $a$ is relatively prime to $m$ and $m$ has a primitive root, $a$ is a member of some cyclic group $V_m$ of order $\phi(m)$.

Given $n$ is relatively prime to $\phi(m)$, $n$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_{\phi(m)}^*$.
Let $t$ be the inverse of $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{\phi(m)}^*$, so $nt\equiv 1\,(\operatorname{mod}\phi(m))$.
Let $nt=s\cdot\phi(m) + 1$ for some integer $s$.

Suppose $x^n \equiv a\,(\operatorname{mod}m)$. Then
\begin{align*}
    (x^n)^t &\equiv a^t\,(\operatorname{mod}m) \\
    x^{s\cdot\phi(m)+1} &\equiv a^t\,(\operatorname{mod}m) \\
    x &\equiv a^t\,(\operatorname{mod}m) & x^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\,(\operatorname{mod}m) \text{ by Euler's theorem}
\end{align*}
As $V_m$ is cyclic, $a\in V_m$ implies $a^t\in V_m$.  This shows a solution exists for $x^n\equiv a\,(\operatorname{mod}m)$.

Questions:

1. Does this look reasonable?
2. It seems even if $a$ is not relatively prime to $m$, $x^n\equiv a\,(\operatorname{mod}m)$ would still have a solution of $a^t$ where t is the inverse of $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{\phi(m)}^*$. Correct?

Comment: 1: Your proof is indeed reasonable. 2: Actually no—for example, $x^3\equiv2\pmod 4$ has no solution.